# What is the Chinese for "Harbin salad"

Tags: word, food

There is a dish from Northern China called Harbin salad in English as well as in Russian. I want to find out what it is called in Chinese.

[Here is a link that describes the dish.](http://officechairtraveller.posterous.com/auntie-shaos-home-style-harbin-salad)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the description, it contains glass noodle (a.k.a. clear noodle, noodle made of bean or potato starch), in that case the glass noodle is the main and other food materials are just sides, though in the picture the side overwhelmed the main. It is called **`东北大拉皮, 哈尔滨大拉皮 or 五彩拉皮`**. 大拉皮 literally means 'grand (dish of) glass noodles'. 五彩 means 'colorful' referring to the sides.

A dish that looks similar but without glass noodle in it is called **`东北大拌菜 or 哈尔滨大拌菜`**. 大拌菜 literally means 'grand mix of food'.

The recipe of both dishes can vary from home to home, restaurant to restaurant. They usually contain Chinese cabbage, carrots, cucumber. Other common materials you may see include beancurd sticks (strips of tofu skin), Chinese cilantro (a.k.a. coriander), turnip. After 1990's people start to put lettuce and cherry tomato in them.

The main difference between the two dishes, other than having glass noodle or not, is the seasoning. Usually 大拉皮 is salty and dressed with chili or mustard, 大拌菜 is sweet and sour.

东北大拉皮/哈尔滨大拉皮 'Grand dish of glass noodles'：

[image: 东北大拉皮]

五彩拉皮 'Colorful glass noodles'：

[image: 五彩拉皮]

东北大拌菜/哈尔滨大拌菜 'Grand mix of food'：

[image: 东北大拌菜]